# Error while loading fine-tuned simpletransformer model in Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, simpletransformers

I am saving and loading a model using `torch.save()` and `torch.load()` commands.

While loading a fine-tuned simple transformer model in Docker Container, I am facing this error which I am not able to resolve:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 594, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 853, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/xlm_roberta/tokenization_xlm_roberta.py", line 161, in __setstate__
    self.sp_model.Load(self.vocab_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sentencepiece.py", line 367, in Load
    return self.LoadFromFile(model_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sentencepiece.py", line 177, in LoadFromFile
    return _sentencepiece.SentencePieceProcessor_LoadFromFile(self, arg)
OSError: Not found: "/home/jupyter/.cache/huggingface/transformers/9df9ae4442348b73950203b63d1b8ed2d18eba68921872aee0c3a9d05b9673c6.00628a9eeb8baf4080d44a0abe9fe8057893de20c7cb6e6423cddbf452f7d4d8": No such file or directory Error #2
```

If anyone has any idea about it, please let me know.

I am using:

- torch ==1.7.1+cu101
- sentence-transformers         0.3.9
- simpletransformers            0.51.15
- transformers                  4.4.2
- tensorflow                    2.2.0

Comment: Does `/home/jupyter` exist in your docker container? Try `docker exec -it <container name> sh -c "test -d /home/jupyter && echo 'exists'"`

Comment: I have checked this out. It exists

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `state_dict` objects - the Python dictionaries as they can be easily saved, updated and restored giving you a flexibility for restoring the model later. Here are the recommended Save/Load methods for saving models with `state_dict`:

**Save**

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

**Load**

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```